# Get the smallest array from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of arrays, I want to get the smallest (shortest) path from `paths` array

```
paths = [ 
   ["LEFT", "RIGHT", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "TOP"],
   ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "TOP"],
   ["TOP", "LEFT"]
];

paths.map((path)=> Math.min(path.length));
```

Comment: what's wrong then ?

Comment: What error are you getting=

Comment: @AnnaJeanine I'm not getting error, I just can't figure out how to do it with `map` function

Comment: what about same length arrays?

Comment: @NinaScholz in my case it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var paths = [
  ["LEFT", "RIGHT", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "TOP"],
  ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "TOP"],
  ["TOP", "LEFT"]
];

console.log(paths.reduce((prev, next) => prev.length > next.length ? next : prev))
```

Comment: @MurhafSousli : you can do... but it may be so long.... it's not the job of map method ;)

Comment: Good this is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array sort method and compare the length of each array. This seems the most straightforward way to me.

```
let paths = [
  ["LEFT", "RIGHT", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "TOP"],
  ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "TOP"],
  ["TOP", "LEFT"]
];
const [shortestPath] = paths .sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length);
console.log(shortestPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect only smaller or equal length arrays.

```js
var paths = [["LEFT", "RIGHT", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "TOP"], ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "TOP"], ["TOP", "LEFT"]],
    result = paths.reduce((r, a, i) => {
        if (!i || a.length < r[0].length) {
            return [a];
        }
        if (a.length === r[0].length) {
            r.push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```